# Extracting characters from a mixed format csv file using Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

So, I have a .csv file which looks like this:

```
station_id year january february ... december
210018     1916 nodata  221          417a
210018     1917 17b     98           44
....
210252     1910 54e     110          nodata
210252     1911 99d     24i          77
...
```

I need to extract letters from a to i (a-i) from the data. These letters mean numbers of missing days per month: a means 1 day and i means 9 missing days. Right now I don't care about 'nodata' cells. After extracting letters from data cells, I want to calculate total number of missing days per month:

```
station_id year january february ... december N_missingdays
210018     1916 nodata  221          417      1(a)
210018     1917 17      98           44       11(b+i)
....
210252     1910 54      110          nodata   8(e+c)
210252     1911 99      24           77       13(d+i)
```

Probably, the best way to do it, is to create a dictionary with station_id, year and number of missing days. Here is what I was trying to do:

```
with open('filepath') as file:
    file_reader = reader(file)
    for i,row in enumerate(file_reader):
        for j,item in enumerate(row):
           if item[len(item)-1]=='a':
                file_reader[i][j]=''
                print file_reader
```

But this function just deleting letters from the file and it doesn't work correctly. I don't know exactly how to extract letters from the .csv file and calculate their meaning. 
The other thing I was trying to do is this:

```
with open('filepath') as file:
    file_reader = reader(file)
        next(file_reader)
        letters_dict={}
        for row in file_reader:
            station_id,year,months = row[1],row[2],row[4:]
            letters_list[station_id,year] = months.count('[0-9][a]') + ... + months.count('[0-9][i]') + letters_dict.get(year, 0) + letters_dict.get(station_id,0)
```

But this code writes in a dictionary only zeroes.

Comment: You should probably try to do some sort of df.stack().value_counts() calculation. Not sure how to break out the end analsyis as a groubpy statement with column names though.

Comment: function value_counts doesn't work - I tried it.